# Customizing the background of an Android notification tile

Tags: android, notifications

I noticed that one of my Android apps has set a custom background for its notification tile, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

How did this application set a custom background for its notification? How can I achieve the same thing in my own application?

Comment: Checkout how to Create a Custom Notification Layout https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification.html

Comment: Thank for answer, but in this link i can find how to create custom notification layout, but i didn't find how to set custom background image / color for it, like on my image. Or may be I am wrong? There are no any manuals about background changes in stack or internet.

Comment: In this line, just replace R.layout.notification_small with your own layout. RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);

Comment: Oh realy, thanks for yours help, will try to customise this layout and use it in RemoteViews builder.

Answer (score -1):

```
NotificationCompat
     .Builder(this, channelId)
     //...
     .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
     .setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))
     .setColorized(true)
     .build()
```