# How android apps show Custom notifications like this one?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications

I am trying to create an android app that shows permanent notification like this one
[image]

How can a notification have all this UI and images? which type of notifications allow this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804120/custom-android-notification-background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom android notification background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804120/custom-android-notification-background)

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification.html:

```
// Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
val notificationLayout = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_small)
val notificationLayoutExpanded = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_large)

// Apply the layouts to the notification
val customNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
        .build()
```